# How to Show Order Details on Checkout Success Page in Opencart 2x

Tags: php, opencart, opencart2.x

I am trying to show order details for successful orders on success page but unable to do so. Another answer here suggests to modify success.php and success.tpl but it's not working on Opencart 2.

What have I tried?

catalog/controller/checkout/success.php

and added new lines in the following code:

```
public function index() {
$this->data['order_id'] = 0; // <-- NEW LINE
$this->data['total'] = 0; // <-- NEW LINE

if (isset($this->session->data['order_id'])) {
    $this->data['order_id'] = $this->session->data['order_id']; // <-- NEW LINE
    $this->data['total'] = $this->cart->getTotal(); // <-- NEW LINE

    $this->cart->clear();

    unset($this->session->data['shipping_method']);
    unset($this->session->data['shipping_methods']);
    unset($this->session->data['payment_method']);
    unset($this->session->data['payment_methods']);
    unset($this->session->data['guest']);
    unset($this->session->data['comment']);
    unset($this->session->data['order_id']);    
    unset($this->session->data['coupon']);
    unset($this->session->data['reward']);
    unset($this->session->data['voucher']);
    unset($this->session->data['vouchers']);
}   

$this->language->load('checkout/success');
```

Now added the following code into success.tpl

```
<?php if($order_id) { ?>
<script type="text/javascript">
// Some code here
arr.push([
    "create_order",
    {order_id: '<?php echo $order_id; ?>', sum: '<?php echo $total; ?>'}
]);
```

But it doesn't show anything on success page. The above code is to show order ID and total but I want to show all details of order including name, address, products, total, shipping, etc. Just like in the order invoice.

Any help will be appreciated. Thank you

Comment: First you need to learn opencart 2x codding changes 
now in opencart 2x supports 
$data[] 
not 
$this->data

Comment: In addition to OBAID's comment, I think `$this->session->data['order_id']` has already been unset by the time the customer reaches the `success` controller.  I know in older versions it was because I had the same problem when setting this up for a client.

Answer (score 4):

What I did on pre 2.0 versions was to actually set a new variable to the session for the order id as I found that `$this->session->data['order_id']` wasn't consistent and sometimes was getting unset by the time the user reached `ControllerCheckoutSuccess`.

If you'd like to use this approach, edit your `catalog/model/checkout/order.php` file. At or about line 302 (within the addOrderHistory method) you'll see where the script checks for order status ids to determine if it should complete the order.

Within that statement, set a new session variable of your choice to the order id passed in, perhaps `$this->session->data['customer_order_id'] = $order_id`

Now you have a session variable that you know will remain consistent since you've created it yourself and OpenCart won't mess with it.

If you're finding that the session order id **IS** remaining consistent in 2.1 > then don't worry about this, just go ahead and use the default session order id variable built in.

The next step will be for you to decide how you want your invoice data loaded, via PHP or Ajax. I wouldn't recommend using Ajax as since this could be manipulated with browser developer tools and may expose other's customer's information. By using PHP and the session you eliminate this risk since a random hacker won't have access to another customer's session.

> **REQUIRED FOR BOTH OPTIONS BELOW:**

Open `catalog/controller/checkout/success.php`

Right after the language file is loaded in your index method add the following:

```
$order_id = false;

// If NOT using the custom variable mentioned SKIP this
if (isset($this->session->data['customer_order_id'])) {
    $order_id = $this->session->data['customer_order_id'];
}
```

If you're using the baked in session data order id, set your order id within that statement:

```
if (isset($this->session->data['order_id'])) {
    $this->cart->clear();

    $order_id = $this->session->data['order_id'];
```

**OPTION 1:**

> Add receipt data to checkout/success.

Find this line:

`$data['button_continue'] = $this->language->get('button_continue');`

Should be around line 77-84 or thereabout.

Here you'll load up and format all your receipt info.

Open `catalog/controller/account/order.php`

On line 108 you'll find the `info` method.

Here's where the fun starts :P

Copy all the relevant info from that method into your checkout success controller just after the `$data['button_continue'] = $this->language->get('button_continue');` line mentioned above.

You'll need to go through this line by line and tweak it because remember this is designed for logged in customers, so you won't want links for returns or reorders etc.

Next you're going to want to make a new template because the `common/success` template is generic and used all over the place.

Copy `catalog/view/theme/(your theme)/template/common/success.tpl`

to: `catalog/view/theme/(your theme)/template/checkout/success.tpl`

Open `catalog/view/theme/default/template/account/order_info.tpl`

The tables you'll need to add to your success template start on line 28 and extend to line 139. If you're using a different theme, you'll need to suss this out for yourself.

Don't forget to change the path to your template in your `checkout/success` controller to your new `checkout/success` tpl file.

**NOTE:**

It's important to remember that all this **SHOULD** be done in a modification package and **NOT** in your core files, but I don't know your situation so that's up to you to decide.

**OPTION 2:**

> Create your own module.
>
> *In my opinion having built for this system since version 1.4 this is the best option.*

Create new controller in modules, let's call it `ControllerModuleReceipt`:

```
<?php

/**
 * Controller class for displaying a receipt on checkout success.
 */
class ControllerModuleReceipt extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Replicates the ControllerAccountOrder::info
     * method for displaying order info in our
     * ControllerCheckoutSuccess::index method
     * 
     * @param  int $order_id   our order id
     * @return mixed           receipt view
     */
    public function index($setting)
    {
        $this->load->language('account/order');
        $this->load->model('account/order');

        if (empty($setting['order_id'])) {
            return;
        }

        $order_id = $setting['order_id'];

        $order_info = $this->model_account_order->getOrder($order_id);

        if ($order_info) {

            $data['text_order_detail']     = $this->language->get('text_order_detail');
            $data['text_invoice_no']       = $this->language->get('text_invoice_no');
            $data['text_order_id']         = $this->language->get('text_order_id');
            $data['text_date_added']       = $this->language->get('text_date_added');
            $data['text_shipping_method']  = $this->language->get('text_shipping_method');
            $data['text_shipping_address'] = $this->language->get('text_shipping_address');
            $data['text_payment_method']   = $this->language->get('text_payment_method');
            $data['text_payment_address']  = $this->language->get('text_payment_address');
            $data['text_history']          = $this->language->get('text_history');
            $data['text_comment']          = $this->language->get('text_comment');

            $data['column_name']           = $this->language->get('column_name');
            $data['column_model']          = $this->language->get('column_model');
            $data['column_quantity']       = $this->language->get('column_quantity');
            $data['column_price']          = $this->language->get('column_price');
            $data['column_total']          = $this->language->get('column_total');
            $data['column_action']         = $this->language->get('column_action');
            $data['column_date_added']     = $this->language->get('column_date_added');
            $data['column_status']         = $this->language->get('column_status');
            $data['column_comment']        = $this->language->get('column_comment');

            $data['invoice_no'] = '';

            if ($order_info['invoice_no']) {
                $data['invoice_no'] = $order_info['invoice_prefix'] . $order_info['invoice_no'];
            }

            $data['order_id']   = $order_id;
            $data['date_added'] = date($this->language->get('date_format_short'), strtotime($order_info['date_added']));

            $format = '{firstname} {lastname}' . "\n" . '{company}' . "\n" . '{address_1}' . "\n" . '{address_2}' . "\n" . '{city} {postcode}' . "\n" . '{zone}' . "\n" . '{country}';

            if ($order_info['payment_address_format']) {
                $format = $order_info['payment_address_format'];
            }

            $find = array(
                '{firstname}',
                '{lastname}',
                '{company}',
                '{address_1}',
                '{address_2}',
                '{city}',
                '{postcode}',
                '{zone}',
                '{zone_code}',
                '{country}'
            );

            $replace = array(
                'firstname' => $order_info['payment_firstname'],
                'lastname'  => $order_info['payment_lastname'],
                'company'   => $order_info['payment_company'],
                'address_1' => $order_info['payment_address_1'],
                'address_2' => $order_info['payment_address_2'],
                'city'      => $order_info['payment_city'],
                'postcode'  => $order_info['payment_postcode'],
                'zone'      => $order_info['payment_zone'],
                'zone_code' => $order_info['payment_zone_code'],
                'country'   => $order_info['payment_country']
            );

            $data['payment_address'] = str_replace(array("\r\n", "\r", "\n"), '<br />', preg_replace(array("/\s\s+/", "/\r\r+/", "/\n\n+/"), '<br />', trim(str_replace($find, $replace, $format))));

            $data['payment_method'] = $order_info['payment_method'];

            $format = '{firstname} {lastname}' . "\n" . '{company}' . "\n" . '{address_1}' . "\n" . '{address_2}' . "\n" . '{city} {postcode}' . "\n" . '{zone}' . "\n" . '{country}';

            if ($order_info['shipping_address_format']) {
                $format = $order_info['shipping_address_format'];
            }

            $find = array(
                '{firstname}',
                '{lastname}',
                '{company}',
                '{address_1}',
                '{address_2}',
                '{city}',
                '{postcode}',
                '{zone}',
                '{zone_code}',
                '{country}'
            );

            $replace = array(
                'firstname' => $order_info['shipping_firstname'],
                'lastname'  => $order_info['shipping_lastname'],
                'company'   => $order_info['shipping_company'],
                'address_1' => $order_info['shipping_address_1'],
                'address_2' => $order_info['shipping_address_2'],
                'city'      => $order_info['shipping_city'],
                'postcode'  => $order_info['shipping_postcode'],
                'zone'      => $order_info['shipping_zone'],
                'zone_code' => $order_info['shipping_zone_code'],
                'country'   => $order_info['shipping_country']
            );

            $data['shipping_address'] = str_replace(array("\r\n", "\r", "\n"), '<br />', preg_replace(array("/\s\s+/", "/\r\r+/", "/\n\n+/"), '<br />', trim(str_replace($find, $replace, $format))));

            $data['shipping_method'] = $order_info['shipping_method'];

            $this->load->model('catalog/product');
            $this->load->model('tool/upload');

            // Products
            $data['products'] = array();

            $products = $this->model_account_order->getOrderProducts($this->request->get['order_id']);

            foreach ($products as $product) {
                $option_data = array();

                $options = $this->model_account_order->getOrderOptions($this->request->get['order_id'], $product['order_product_id']);

                foreach ($options as $option) {
                    $value = false;

                    if ($option['type'] == 'file') {
                        $upload_info = $this->model_tool_upload->getUploadByCode($option['value']);

                        if ($upload_info) {
                            $value = $upload_info['name'];
                        }
                    }

                    if (! $value) {
                        $value = $option['value'];
                    }

                    $option_data[] = array(
                        'name'  => $option['name'],
                        'value' => (utf8_strlen($value) > 20 ? utf8_substr($value, 0, 20) . '..' : $value)
                    );
                }

                $product_info = $this->model_catalog_product->getProduct($product['product_id']);

                $data['products'][] = array(
                    'name'     => $product['name'],
                    'model'    => $product['model'],
                    'option'   => $option_data,
                    'quantity' => $product['quantity'],
                    'price'    => $this->currency->format($product['price'] + ($this->config->get('config_tax') ? $product['tax'] : 0), $order_info['currency_code'], $order_info['currency_value']),
                    'total'    => $this->currency->format($product['total'] + ($this->config->get('config_tax') ? ($product['tax'] * $product['quantity']) : 0), $order_info['currency_code'], $order_info['currency_value'])
                );
            }

            // Voucher
            $data['vouchers'] = array();

            $vouchers = $this->model_account_order->getOrderVouchers($this->request->get['order_id']);

            foreach ($vouchers as $voucher) {
                $data['vouchers'][] = array(
                    'description' => $voucher['description'],
                    'amount'      => $this->currency->format($voucher['amount'], $order_info['currency_code'], $order_info['currency_value'])
                );
            }

            // Totals
            $data['totals'] = array();

            $totals = $this->model_account_order->getOrderTotals($this->request->get['order_id']);

            foreach ($totals as $total) {
                $data['totals'][] = array(
                    'title' => $total['title'],
                    'text'  => $this->currency->format($total['value'], $order_info['currency_code'], $order_info['currency_value']),
                );
            }

            $data['comment'] = nl2br($order_info['comment']);

            if (file_exists(DIR_TEMPLATE . $this->config->get('config_template') . '/template/module/receipt.tpl')) {
                return $this->load->view($this->config->get('config_template') . '/template/module/receipt.tpl', $data);
            } else {
                return $this->load->view('default/template/module/receipt.tpl', $data);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**TEMPLATE:**

Next let's create the template in `catalog/views/theme/default/module/receipt.tpl`

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-hover">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <td class="text-left" colspan="2"><?= $text_order_detail; ?></td>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="text-left" style="width: 50%;"><?php if ($invoice_no): ?>
        <b><?= $text_invoice_no; ?></b> <?= $invoice_no; ?><br />
        <?php endif; ?>
        <b><?= $text_order_id; ?></b> #<?= $order_id; ?><br />
        <b><?= $text_date_added; ?></b> <?= $date_added; ?></td>
      <td class="text-left"><?php if ($payment_method): ?>
        <b><?= $text_payment_method; ?></b> <?= $payment_method; ?><br />
        <?php endif; ?>
        <?php if ($shipping_method): ?>
        <b><?= $text_shipping_method; ?></b> <?= $shipping_method; ?>
        <?php endif; ?></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<table class="table table-bordered table-hover">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <td class="text-left" style="width: 50%;"><?= $text_payment_address; ?></td>
      <?php if ($shipping_address): ?>
      <td class="text-left"><?= $text_shipping_address; ?></td>
      <?php endif; ?>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="text-left"><?= $payment_address; ?></td>
      <?php if ($shipping_address): ?>
      <td class="text-left"><?= $shipping_address; ?></td>
      <?php endif; ?>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<div class="table-responsive">
  <table class="table table-bordered table-hover">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <td class="text-left"><?= $column_name; ?></td>
        <td class="text-left"><?= $column_model; ?></td>
        <td class="text-right"><?= $column_quantity; ?></td>
        <td class="text-right"><?= $column_price; ?></td>
        <td class="text-right"><?= $column_total; ?></td>
        <?php if ($products): ?>
        <td style="width: 20px;"></td>
        <?php endif; ?>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <?php foreach ($products as $product): ?>
      <tr>
        <td class="text-left"><?= $product['name']; ?>
          <?php foreach ($product['option'] as $option): ?>
          <br />
          &nbsp;<small> - <?= $option['name']; ?>: <?= $option['value']; ?></small>
          <?php endforeach; ?></td>
        <td class="text-left"><?= $product['model']; ?></td>
        <td class="text-right"><?= $product['quantity']; ?></td>
        <td class="text-right"><?= $product['price']; ?></td>
        <td class="text-right"><?= $product['total']; ?></td>
        <td class="text-right" style="white-space: nowrap;"><?php if ($product['reorder']): ?>
          <a href="<?= $product['reorder']; ?>" data-toggle="tooltip" title="<?= $button_reorder; ?>" class="btn btn-primary"><i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i></a>
          <?php endif; ?>
          <a href="<?= $product['return']; ?>" data-toggle="tooltip" title="<?= $button_return; ?>" class="btn btn-danger"><i class="fa fa-reply"></i></a></td>
      </tr>
      <?php endforeach; ?>
      <?php foreach ($vouchers as $voucher): ?>
      <tr>
        <td class="text-left"><?= $voucher['description']; ?></td>
        <td class="text-left"></td>
        <td class="text-right">1</td>
        <td class="text-right"><?= $voucher['amount']; ?></td>
        <td class="text-right"><?= $voucher['amount']; ?></td>
        <?php if ($products): ?>
        <td></td>
        <?php endif; ?>
      </tr>
      <?php endforeach; ?>
    </tbody>
    <tfoot>
      <?php foreach ($totals as $total): ?>
      <tr>
        <td colspan="3"></td>
        <td class="text-right"><b><?= $total['title']; ?></b></td>
        <td class="text-right"><?= $total['text']; ?></td>
        <?php if ($products): ?>
        <td></td>
        <?php endif; ?>
      </tr>
      <?php endforeach; ?>
    </tfoot>
  </table>
</div>
<?php if ($comment): ?>
<table class="table table-bordered table-hover">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <td class="text-left"><?= $text_comment; ?></td>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="text-left"><?= $comment; ?></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Once again, if using your own theme you'll need to adjust this.

**ADD MODULE TO CHECKOUT SUCCESS**

Back in the checkout success controller we need to add the module.

Find `$data['content_bottom'] = $this->load->controller('common/content_bottom');`

After that line add this:

```
$data['receipt'] = false;
if ($order_id) {
    $data['receipt'] = $this->load->controller('module/receipt', array('order_id' => $order_id));
}
```

**ADD TO SUCCESS TEMPLATE**

Open `catalog/view/theme/default/common/success.tpl`

After `<?php echo $text_message; ?>` add:

```
<?php if ($receipt): ?>
  <?= $receipt; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

And that should be it. Once again it's best to add the changes to core files via a modification, but by creating your own module it's MUCH easier to add a modification, much less to deal with.

I haven't tested the code above but it should work or have minimal errors.  Feel free to post any errors and I'll be happy to help fix them.

Comment: Thnx! for the first part of the solution, its in the right direction for what i want to archive (keep the orderid in the success page), but when the payment goes through Paypal the custom order id is missing too. any ideas? oc2.1.0.1

Comment: Sorry man, I haven't worked with OpenCart in many years, I don't think I even have an existing copy on my system. Are you sending the custom order id to PayPal. As I remember there are fields for PayPal that can be customized for your own data.

Comment: it was an GET/POST issue related with the modern browsers. no need for custom data. the id it is been send but not returned. fixed now with: https://forum.opencart.com/viewtopic.php?f=190&t=219851

Answer (score 0):

The awesome code that **Vince** post works!

But I found some **Errors and PHP Notices** and product table was not showing up, so i did some modifications in the code and it works 100% now.

I used the OPTION 2 and Opencart 2.2 for the tests.

Here is the code:

**Receipit.php in CONTROLLER/MODULE**

```
<?php

/**
 * Controller class for displaying a receipt on checkout success.
 */
class ControllerModuleReceipt extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Replicates the ControllerAccountOrder::info
     * method for displaying order info in our
     * ControllerCheckoutSuccess::index method
     * 
     * @param  int $order_id   our order id
     * @return mixed           receipt view
     */
    public function index($setting)
    {
        $this->load->language('account/order');
        $this->load->model('account/order');

        if (empty($setting['order_id'])) {
            return;
        }

        $order_id = $setting['order_id'];

        $order_info = $this->model_account_order->getOrder($order_id);

        if ($order_info) {

            $data['text_order_detail']     = $this->language->get('text_order_detail');
            $data['text_invoice_no']       = $this->language->get('text_invoice_no');
            $data['text_order_id']         = $this->language->get('text_order_id');
            $data['text_date_added']       = $this->language->get('text_date_added');
            $data['text_shipping_method']  = $this->language->get('text_shipping_method');
            $data['text_shipping_address'] = $this->language->get('text_shipping_address');
            $data['text_payment_method']   = $this->language->get('text_payment_method');
            $data['text_payment_address']  = $this->language->get('text_payment_address');
            $data['text_history']          = $this->language->get('text_history');
            $data['text_comment']          = $this->language->get('text_comment');

            $data['column_name']           = $this->language->get('column_name');
            $data['column_model']          = $this->language->get('column_model');
            $data['column_quantity']       = $this->language->get('column_quantity');
            $data['column_price']          = $this->language->get('column_price');
            $data['column_total']          = $this->language->get('column_total');
            $data['column_action']         = $this->language->get('column_action');
            $data['column_date_added']     = $this->language->get('column_date_added');
            $data['column_status']         = $this->language->get('column_status');
            $data['column_comment']        = $this->language->get('column_comment');

            $data['invoice_no'] = '';

            if ($order_info['invoice_no']) {
                $data['invoice_no'] = $order_info['invoice_prefix'] . $order_info['invoice_no'];
            }

            $data['order_id']   = $order_id;
            $data['date_added'] = date($this->language->get('date_format_short'), strtotime($order_info['date_added']));

            $format = '{firstname} {lastname}' . "\n" . '{company}' . "\n" . '{address_1}' . "\n" . '{address_2}' . "\n" . '{city} {postcode}' . "\n" . '{zone}' . "\n" . '{country}';

            if ($order_info['payment_address_format']) {
                $format = $order_info['payment_address_format'];
            }

            $find = array(
                '{firstname}',
                '{lastname}',
                '{company}',
                '{address_1}',
                '{address_2}',
                '{city}',
                '{postcode}',
                '{zone}',
                '{zone_code}',
                '{country}'
            );

            $replace = array(
                'firstname' => $order_info['payment_firstname'],
                'lastname'  => $order_info['payment_lastname'],
                'company'   => $order_info['payment_company'],
                'address_1' => $order_info['payment_address_1'],
                'address_2' => $order_info['payment_address_2'],
                'city'      => $order_info['payment_city'],
                'postcode'  => $order_info['payment_postcode'],
                'zone'      => $order_info['payment_zone'],
                'zone_code' => $order_info['payment_zone_code'],
                'country'   => $order_info['payment_country']
            );

            $data['payment_address'] = str_replace(array("\r\n", "\r", "\n"), '<br />', preg_replace(array("/\s\s+/", "/\r\r+/", "/\n\n+/"), '<br />', trim(str_replace($find, $replace, $format))));

            $data['payment_method'] = $order_info['payment_method'];

            $format = '{firstname} {lastname}' . "\n" . '{company}' . "\n" . '{address_1}' . "\n" . '{address_2}' . "\n" . '{city} {postcode}' . "\n" . '{zone}' . "\n" . '{country}';

            if ($order_info['shipping_address_format']) {
                $format = $order_info['shipping_address_format'];
            }

            $find = array(
                '{firstname}',
                '{lastname}',
                '{company}',
                '{address_1}',
                '{address_2}',
                '{city}',
                '{postcode}',
                '{zone}',
                '{zone_code}',
                '{country}'
            );

            $replace = array(
                'firstname' => $order_info['shipping_firstname'],
                'lastname'  => $order_info['shipping_lastname'],
                'company'   => $order_info['shipping_company'],
                'address_1' => $order_info['shipping_address_1'],
                'address_2' => $order_info['shipping_address_2'],
                'city'      => $order_info['shipping_city'],
                'postcode'  => $order_info['shipping_postcode'],
                'zone'      => $order_info['shipping_zone'],
                'zone_code' => $order_info['shipping_zone_code'],
                'country'   => $order_info['shipping_country']
            );

            $data['shipping_address'] = str_replace(array("\r\n", "\r", "\n"), '<br />', preg_replace(array("/\s\s+/", "/\r\r+/", "/\n\n+/"), '<br />', trim(str_replace($find, $replace, $format))));

            $data['shipping_method'] = $order_info['shipping_method'];

            $this->load->model('catalog/product');
            $this->load->model('tool/upload');

            // Products
            $data['products'] = array();

            $products = $this->model_account_order->getOrderProducts($order_id);

            foreach ($products as $product) {
                $option_data = array();

                $options = $this->model_account_order->getOrderOptions($order_id, $product['order_product_id']);

                foreach ($options as $option) {
                    $value = false;

                    if ($option['type'] == 'file') {
                        $upload_info = $this->model_tool_upload->getUploadByCode($option['value']);

                        if ($upload_info) {
                            $value = $upload_info['name'];
                        }
                    }

                    if (! $value) {
                        $value = $option['value'];
                    }

                    $option_data[] = array(
                        'name'  => $option['name'],
                        'value' => (utf8_strlen($value) > 20 ? utf8_substr($value, 0, 20) . '..' : $value)
                    );
                }

                $product_info = $this->model_catalog_product->getProduct($product['product_id']);

                $data['products'][] = array(
                    'name'     => $product['name'],
                    'model'    => $product['model'],
                    'option'   => $option_data,
                    'quantity' => $product['quantity'],
                    'price'    => $this->currency->format($product['price'] + ($this->config->get('config_tax') ? $product['tax'] : 0), $order_info['currency_code'], $order_info['currency_value']),
                    'total'    => $this->currency->format($product['total'] + ($this->config->get('config_tax') ? ($product['tax'] * $product['quantity']) : 0), $order_info['currency_code'], $order_info['currency_value'])
                );
            }

            // Voucher
            $data['vouchers'] = array();

            $vouchers = $this->model_account_order->getOrderVouchers($order_id);

            foreach ($vouchers as $voucher) {
                $data['vouchers'][] = array(
                    'description' => $voucher['description'],
                    'amount'      => $this->currency->format($voucher['amount'], $order_info['currency_code'], $order_info['currency_value'])
                );
            }

            // Totals
            $data['totals'] = array();

            $totals = $this->model_account_order->getOrderTotals($order_id);

            foreach ($totals as $total) {
                $data['totals'][] = array(
                    'title' => $total['title'],
                    'text'  => $this->currency->format($total['value'], $order_info['currency_code'], $order_info['currency_value']),
                );
            }

            $data['comment'] = nl2br($order_info['comment']);

            if (file_exists(DIR_TEMPLATE . $this->config->get('config_template') . '/template/module/receipt.tpl')) {
                return $this->load->view($this->config->get('config_template') . '/template/module/receipt.tpl', $data);
            } else {
                return $this->load->view('/module/receipt.tpl', $data);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Receipit.tpl in TEMPLATES/MODULE**

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-hover">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <td class="text-left" colspan="2"><?= $text_order_detail; ?></td>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="text-left" style="width: 50%;"><?php if ($invoice_no): ?>
        <b><?= $text_invoice_no; ?></b> <?= $invoice_no; ?><br />
        <?php endif; ?>
        <b><?= $text_order_id; ?></b> #<?= $order_id; ?><br />
        <b><?= $text_date_added; ?></b> <?= $date_added; ?></td>
      <td class="text-left"><?php if ($payment_method): ?>
        <b><?= $text_payment_method; ?></b> <?= $payment_method; ?><br />
        <?php endif; ?>
        <?php if ($shipping_method): ?>
        <b><?= $text_shipping_method; ?></b> <?= $shipping_method; ?>
        <?php endif; ?></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<table class="table table-bordered table-hover">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <td class="text-left" style="width: 50%;"><?= $text_payment_address; ?></td>
      <?php if ($shipping_address): ?>
      <td class="text-left"><?= $text_shipping_address; ?></td>
      <?php endif; ?>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="text-left"><?= $payment_address; ?></td>
      <?php if ($shipping_address): ?>
      <td class="text-left"><?= $shipping_address; ?></td>
      <?php endif; ?>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<div class="table-responsive">
  <table class="table table-bordered table-hover">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <td class="text-left" style="display: table-cell"><?= $column_name; ?></td>
        <td class="text-left" style="display: none"><?= $column_model; ?></td>
        <td class="text-right" style="display: table-cell"><?= $column_quantity; ?></td>
        <td class="text-right" style="display: table-cell"><?= $column_price; ?></td>
        <td class="text-right" style="display: table-cell"><?= $column_total; ?></td>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <?php foreach ($products as $product): ?>
      <tr>
        <td class="text-left" style="display: table-cell"><?= $product['name']; ?>
          <?php foreach ($product['option'] as $option): ?>
          <br />
          &nbsp;<small> - <?= $option['name']; ?>: <?= $option['value']; ?></small>
          <?php endforeach; ?></td>
        <td class="text-left" style="display: none"><?= $product['model']; ?></td>
        <td class="text-right" style="display: table-cell"><?= $product['quantity']; ?></td>
        <td class="text-right" style="display: table-cell"><?= $product['price']; ?></td>
        <td class="text-right" style="display: table-cell"><?= $product['total']; ?></td>
      </tr>
      <?php endforeach; ?>
      <?php foreach ($vouchers as $voucher): ?>
      <tr>
        <td class="text-left"><?= $voucher['description']; ?></td>
        <td class="text-left"></td>
        <td class="text-right">1</td>
        <td class="text-right"><?= $voucher['amount']; ?></td>
        <td class="text-right"><?= $voucher['amount']; ?></td>
      </tr>
      <?php endforeach; ?>
    </tbody>
    <tfoot>
      <?php foreach ($totals as $total): ?>
      <tr>
        <td colspan="2"></td>
        <td class="text-right"><b><?= $total['title']; ?></b></td>
        <td class="text-right"><?= $total['text']; ?></td>
      </tr>
      <?php endforeach; ?>
    </tfoot>
  </table>
</div>
<?php if ($comment): ?>
<table class="table table-bordered table-hover">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <td class="text-left"><?= $text_comment; ?></td>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="text-left"><?= $comment; ?></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<?php endif; ?>
```

**NOTE**

Before entering the codes in your store, test on a backup to make sure that your store will not be impaired.

If this code has any flaws, please let me know here

Thanks!