# How can we use order details on checkout success page of Opencart Template?

Tags: php, opencart, opencart2.x, opencart-module

I need to add order data in OpenCart 2.1.0.1 template on checkout/success page. I added the below code in `view/theme/name/template/common/success.tpl` but it is not showing order data, **(values are empty because there is no order id in `$this->session->data`)**.

```
<?php if(!empty($orderid)) echo $orderid; ?>
<?php if(!empty($email)) echo $email; ?>
<?php if(!empty($fname)) echo $fname; ?>
<?php if(!empty($lname)) echo $lname; ?>
```

In `/catalog/controller/checkout/success.php` I have defined these PHP variables:

```
$this->data['orderid'] = $$this->session->data['order_id'];
$this->data['fname'] = $this->session->data['guest']['firstname'];
$this->data['lname'] = $this->session->data['guest']['lastname'];

$this->load->model('account/order');
$order = $this->model_account_order->getOrder($this->session->data['order_id']);
if($order) {
$this->data['email'] = $order['email'];    
}
```

Can anyone guide what am I missing and why these values are not loading in`.tpl` file, and what is the solution. Even hard coded values are also not retrieved in .tpl.

**Values of $this->session->data:**

```
(
[language] => en
[currency] => USD
[user_id] => 9
[token] => 5ZiNOGeVjCdg4gefNkDLcHzF1zMUVKgA
[account] => guest
[payment_address] => Array
    (
        [firstname] => sdfsdf
        [lastname] => adfafa
        [company] => 
        [address_1] => test test test
        [address_2] => 
        [postcode] => 34324
        [city] => sdfsdfd
        [country_id] => 216
        [zone_id] => 3396
        [country] => Turkmenistan
        [iso_code_2] => TM
        [iso_code_3] => TKM
        [address_format] => 
        [custom_field] => Array
            (
            )
        [zone] => Ahal Welayaty
        [zone_code] => A
    )
[shipping_address] => Array
    (
        [firstname] => sdfsdf
        [lastname] => adfafa
        [company] => 
        [address_1] => test test test
        [address_2] => 
        [postcode] => 34324
        [city] => sdfsdfd
        [country_id] => 216
        [zone_id] => 3396
        [country] => Turkmenistan
        [iso_code_2] => TM
        [iso_code_3] => TKM
        [address_format] => 
        [zone] => Ahal Welayaty
        [zone_code] => A
        [custom_field] => Array
            (
            )
    )
)
```

Answer (score 3):

#### Correct variable name

Opencart 2.0 and up doesn't use `$this->data` for templates.  Instead simply use `$data`.  SO instead of:

```
$this->data['hardcoded'] = "HARD CODED";
```

You can write:

```
$data['hardcoded'] = "HARD CODED";
```

#### Position of code

All order data is cleared at the top of the controller so if you need to access it make sure you define those variables before:

```
if (isset($this->session->data['order_id'])) {
```

#### Efficiency & Accuracy of data

Normally, `$this->session->data['guest']` is *only* defined if customer is not logged in.  The best way to use order data would be to get data from the order itself and assign it to a single array since all the conditionals have already been dealt with when it was created.  This saves you the trouble of re-defining each variable and checking logged in status, etc:

```
$this->load->model('checkout/order');
$data['order'] = $this->model_checkout_order->getOrder($this->session->data['order_id']);
```

Then in your tpl you can access anything about the order in the `$order` array:

```
$order['order_id']
$order['firstname']
```

Comment: Not working. `$order` is empty in tbl. There is a complicated method shown in this answer, can it be the only solution? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35290034/how-to-show-order-details-on-checkout-success-page-in-opencart-2x

Comment: @XIMRX - with all due respect I work on Opencart full time and the above solution will work.  If it doesn't work for you then you are missing something.  Perhaps you need to refresh your modifications cache?

Comment: In $this->session->data there is no order id. (See dump value in updated question)

Comment: If an order has been confirmed then `$this->session->data['order_id']` will not be empty when the page loads.  Make sure you pay attention to the position of your code as specified in my answer.

Comment: I am testing for 'bank transfer method' can this be the reason of no order_id?

Comment: @XIMRX - no that would not affect anything.  OpenCart sets the order_id as a session variable as soon as you get to the confirmation step of checkout.  So before you even confirm the order that order_id exists.  Did you try clearing your modification cache?  are you sure you have the code executing before the order_id is cleared?  are you able to see hard coded values now?

Comment: in success page you not get order_id using `$this->session->data['order_id']`. order_id already  unset.

Comment: I have the same problem with oc 2.1.0.1 / journal / paypal payment. I cannot get the order_id in success page

Answer (score 0):

is the $data['order'] bit right in

```
$this->load->model('checkout/order');
$data['order'] = $this->model_checkout_order->getOrder($this->session->data['order_id']);
```

should it not be?

```
$this->load->model('checkout/order');
$order = $this->model_checkout_order->getOrder($this->session->data['order_id']);
```